# How to create MultiServer and customer - java simulation

Tags: java, random, simulation

How can I change the number of servers in this code into an increment number : 5, 10, 15, 10 , and during the increment, I can check/ calculate the waiting time ?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Simulate3 {
    private static boolean openPosition;
    private static double fractionAvg = 0.0;
    private static DecimalFormat percent;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double  Mean_Exponential_iat = 10.0;
        double  Mean_erlang_completion_distribution = 2.0;
        int     Time_until_theEnd_of_WorkDay = 8;
        /**
         * By starting and finishing shift with 1 server, almost 98.484848% of customers wait more than 6 mins with the avg wait time at 218 hours.
         * With 2 servers the avg wait time is 13 hours with 69.1489% waiting more than 6 mins. 
         * With 3 servers the avg waiting time is 26mins with  0% of customers waiting more than 6 mins. 
         * Therefore the optimal allocation will be by assigning 2 servers to start off the shift and when the need arises, open a new position of service.
         * If 1 server alone starts, the fraction in close to 16%. 
         * By starting with 2 servers the fraction is 4.3%.
         */

        int The_number_of_servers_in_the_branch =0;         
        long seed = +5; // The starting seed for the random number generator
        int trials =10;//The number of times the simulation will be repeated for the average statistics

        for (int i = 1; i <= trials; i++)// Conduct a number of trials in order to get the average fraction of customers waiting more than 6 mins. 
                                         //Use different seed in each trial.
        {
        simulateNServers(Mean_Exponential_iat, Mean_erlang_completion_distribution, Time_until_theEnd_of_WorkDay, The_number_of_servers_in_the_branch, seed);
        seed++;

            }

        double trialAvg = fractionAvg/trials;
        percent = new DecimalFormat("0.#%");

        System.out.println("=============================================================================");
    //  System.out.println("////");
        System.out.println("Average percent of task waiting more than 6 minutes (100 trials) : "+  percent.format(trialAvg));

        System.out.println("=============================================================================");



    }

    /**
     * Static method to run a simulation with certain parameters. It outputs the following statistical data.
     * 
     * Average waiting time   : 
     * Server free fraction   : [The percentage of the servers being free]
     * Maximum queue length   : 
     * Total customers arrived: [Total arrivals of customers within the work-day]
     * Total customers served : [Total customers served within the work-day]
     * Total customers >6min  : [Total number of customers that waited more than 6 minutes to be served, within the work-day]
     * fraction               : [Percentage of customers that waited more than 6 minutes in the queue]
     * 
     * @param lambdaA : Mean of exponential inter-arrival distribution.
     *            
     * @param lambdaS : Mean of erlang completion distribution.
     *            
     * @param tEnd : The time until the end of the work-day
     *            
     * @param nserv :  The number of servers in the branch
     *           
     * @param seed 
     */
    public static void simulateNServers(double Mean_Exponential_iat, double Mean_erlang_completion_distribution, double Time_until_theEnd_of_WorkDay, int The_number_of_servers_in_the_branch, long seed) 
    {
        The_number_of_servers_in_the_branch +=5;
        Queue q = new Queue(); // Initializes up the Queue
        ArrayList<Server> serverFree = new ArrayList<Server>(); // Create list of servers
        MyRandom r = new MyRandom(seed); // Initializes the random number generator
        int k = 10; // Initializes the kappa of the Erlang distribution

        double clock = 0; // Start of time
        double Time_to_next_arrival = 0.0; // Time to next arrival
        //double[] tnc = new double[nserv]; // Times of size nserv of completion for every server [i]
                                            // 
        double endTime = Time_until_theEnd_of_WorkDay; // Minutes until endtime
        int Number_of_Total_Events = 0; // Number of total events
        int Number_of_total_arrivals = 0; // Number of total arrivals
        double The_Time_to_the_NextEvent = 0.0; // The time to the next event
        int Max_Q_length = 0; // Max Q length

        double Time_free_at_each_instance = 0.0; // Time free at each instance
        double Total_server_free_time = 0.0; // Total server free time
        double ttServerFree = 0.0;
        double Total_Waiting_Time = 0.0; // Total waiting time
        double Total_Number_of_Tasks = 0.0; // Total Number of Customers
        double Number_of_customers_waiting_more_than_6Minutes = 0.0; // Number of customers waiting more than 6 minutes
        int The_Total_Number_of_Servers_BUSY_for_all_events = 0;    // The total number of servers busy for all events  
        int prevHour = 0;       // Keeping track of which hour has finished
        int hourStartEvent = 0;
        int serverSum = 5;
        double serverHourlyAvg = 0.0;


        for (int i = 0; i < The_number_of_servers_in_the_branch; i++)  // Initialize the servers' status
            {
            serverFree.add(new Server(true));
            }


        Server tmpSrv = serverFree.get(0); // Initialise the first completion time to 0.0
        tmpSrv.setTnc(0.0);
        serverFree.set(0, tmpSrv);

        // Primary simulation loop
        while (true) {

            boolean arrivalEvent = false; // The type of the next event, arrival
                                            // or otherwise
            boolean serviceEvent = false; // The type of the next event, service
                                            // or otherwise
            // Keep track of previous event for server free statistics
            double prevEvent = 0.0;
            // Check if the length of the Q is the largest
            if (q.length() > Max_Q_length) 
                {
                Max_Q_length = q.length();
                }
                //Keep track of the fraction of customers waiting more than 6mins
                //This should not exceed 5% on average
            double fraction = Number_of_customers_waiting_more_than_6Minutes / Total_Number_of_Tasks;

            //System.out.println("============================================ " );

            //System.out.println("fraction: "   + fraction); // Print out the fraction per event

            int servers=serverFree.size(); // Prints out the number of servers

            //System.out.println("============================================ " );
            //System.out.println("nserv: "  + nserv);
            // Keep track of how many servers are busy
            The_Total_Number_of_Servers_BUSY_for_all_events += busyServersNo(serverFree);   
            double tnc;// Get the next completion time from all servers
            Server tmp = getNextTNC(serverFree); 
            if(tmp!=null) tnc = tmp.getTnc();
            else tnc=Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
            int tnc_index = serverFree.indexOf(tmp);

            // Check if the next event is a feasible arrival time
            The_Time_to_the_NextEvent  = Math.min(Time_to_next_arrival, tnc);
            if (The_Time_to_the_NextEvent  == Time_to_next_arrival && Time_to_next_arrival != tnc) 
            {
                arrivalEvent = true;
                serviceEvent = false;
            } else if (The_Time_to_the_NextEvent  == tnc && Time_to_next_arrival != tnc) 
            {
                serviceEvent = true;
                arrivalEvent = false;
            } else if (Time_to_next_arrival == tnc) {
                arrivalEvent = true;
            }

            // Update the clock
            if (The_Time_to_the_NextEvent  != Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
                prevEvent = clock;
                clock = The_Time_to_the_NextEvent ;
            }

            /**
             * In this block I'll be keeping some statistics for the average
             * allocation of servers per hour
             */
            int currHour=(int) clock;
                if(currHour==prevHour)
                {
                serverSum+=servers;
                }
                else if (currHour>=prevHour)
                {
                serverHourlyAvg= (double) serverSum/(Number_of_Total_Events - hourStartEvent);

                System.out.println("Avg servers for hour    "+ currHour  +  " : "+  serverHourlyAvg);
                serverSum = 0;
                hourStartEvent=   Number_of_Total_Events ;
                prevHour=currHour;
            }

            /**
             * Every time the cycle begins there needs to be a check whether the optimality constraint is met. 
             * This constraint is that the queue is no larger than 6 customers. 
             * If it is not, then the algorithm needs to set up a flag that will increase the number of servers until the constraint is satisfied.
             * 
             */
            if (q.length()>10) 
            {
                openPosition=true;
            }
                else openPosition=false;

            int id = getFreeServer(serverFree); // Get the index of the next available server

            if (q.isEmpty() && clock >= endTime && tnc == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) // BRANCH_1// Check if the condition to stop the simulation has been met.
            {
                percent = new DecimalFormat("0.0#%");
                System.out.println("==================================================================");
                System.out.println("The number of servers : "   + servers);
                System.out.println("Maximum queue length: " + Max_Q_length);
                System.out.println("Total tasks arrived: " + Number_of_total_arrivals);
                System.out.println("Total tasks served :    " + (int) Total_Number_of_Tasks);
                System.out.println("The_number_of_servers_in_the_branch : " + The_number_of_servers_in_the_branch);
                System.out.println("Average waiting time: " + 60*  Total_Waiting_Time / Total_Number_of_Tasks +   "    minutes");
                System.out.println("Server free fraction: " + percent.format(Total_server_free_time / ttServerFree));

                System.out.println("Total tasks waiting >6min  : " + (int) Number_of_customers_waiting_more_than_6Minutes);
                System.out.println(" fraction              : "  + fraction);
                fractionAvg+=fraction;
                break;

            }


            if (arrivalEvent && clock < endTime)  // BRANCH_2// This is an arrival event and the end time is not reached
                {
                if (id != -1)
                    Time_free_at_each_instance = clock - prevEvent;
                    ttServerFree += Time_free_at_each_instance;
                    Total_server_free_time  += Time_free_at_each_instance * freeServersNo(serverFree);

                if (freeServersNo(serverFree) != 0) // Report how many servers are free and for how long
                    //System.out.println(freeServersNo(serverFree) + " server(s) are free for " + timeFree + " hours. Total= " + ttServer);

                    Time_to_next_arrival = clock + r.nextExponential(getLambda(clock));// Sample for next arrival time so long that it doens't exceed endTime
                        if (Time_to_next_arrival > Time_until_theEnd_of_WorkDay) 
                        {
                            Time_to_next_arrival = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
                        }
                        Number_of_total_arrivals++;


                if (id != -1) // BRANCH_3_YES // Inner conditional loop to check if there is at least one server free
                    { // Mark the server as busy by replacing the object in the arraylist
                    Server tmpSrv0 = serverFree.get(id);
                    tmpSrv0.setState(false);                                    
                    tmpSrv0.setTnc(clock + r.nextErlang(k, Mean_erlang_completion_distribution)); // Sample for time of next completion
                    serverFree.set(id, tmpSrv0);
                    } 
                else {// BRANCH_3_NO                    
                    q.put(clock);// Put person in the queue
                    // If there is need for servers add one here
                    if (openPosition) serverFree.add(new Server(true));
                }
                // Print out the arrival event
                System.out.println(" Number_of_Total_Events arrival: " + Number_of_Total_Events + "  " + "" + " Queue length: " + q.length() + " Time: " + clock);

                if (q.isEmpty()) 
                {
                    // System.out.println("Guy is served, has waited: 0.0");
                    Total_Number_of_Tasks++;
                }
            } 

            else 
                {               
                if (serviceEvent) // BRANCH_4_YES// This is a service completion event
                    {
                    if (id != -1)
                        Time_free_at_each_instance = clock - prevEvent;
                        ttServerFree += Time_free_at_each_instance;
                        Total_server_free_time  += Time_free_at_each_instance * freeServersNo(serverFree);

                    if (freeServersNo(serverFree) != 0)// Report how many servers are free and for how long

                    System.out.println(freeServersNo(serverFree) + " server(s) are free for " + Time_free_at_each_instance + " hours." + " Total_server_free_time  : " + Total_server_free_time );
                    // BRANCH_5_YES// Inner conditional loop to check if the
                    // queue is empty
                    if (q.isEmpty()) 
                    {

                        // If there is no more need; release the additional server
                        if (!openPosition && serverFree.size()>The_number_of_servers_in_the_branch && id!=-1) serverFree.remove(id);

                        // Get the first busy server and release them
                        int busy = serverFree.indexOf(getNextTNC(serverFree));
                        if (busy != -1){
                            // Mark the server as busy by replacing the object in the arraylist
                            Server tmpSrv1 = serverFree.get(busy);
                            tmpSrv1.setState(true);
                            serverFree.set(busy, tmpSrv1);
                        }

                        if (busy != -1){
                            Server tmpSrv2 = serverFree.get(busy);
                            tmpSrv2.setTnc(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
                            serverFree.set(busy, tmpSrv2);
                        }


                    }// End of yes in Condition 5
                    else {// BRANCH_5_NO//
                            // Get person from queue
                        double t = q.get();

                        // Log the served customer
                        Total_Number_of_Tasks++;
                        // Check which customers waited more than 6 minutes (0.1
                        // of the hour)
                        if ((clock - t) > 0.1) 
                        {

                            Number_of_customers_waiting_more_than_6Minutes++; // If it took more than 6 minutes to serve, log it.
                        }
                        System.out.println("Tasks is served, has waited: "      + (clock - t));

                        Total_Waiting_Time += (clock - t);  // Update the sum of waiting times

                        // Sample for time of next completion
                        Server tmpSrv3 = serverFree.get(tnc_index);
                        tmpSrv3.setTnc(clock + r.nextErlang(k, Mean_erlang_completion_distribution));
                        serverFree.set(tnc_index, tmpSrv3);

                    }// End of no in Condition 5
                        // Write out the Completion of the event
                    int event = tnc_index + 1;
                    System.out.println(" Number_of_Total_Events : "+ Number_of_Total_Events + "  " + "completed : " + event + "  " + "Queue length: " + q.length() + " Time: " + clock);

                }// End of Condition 4
                else {// BRANCH_4_NO//
                        // Set next arrival time to very large number
                    Time_to_next_arrival = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
                }// End of Infinite arrival time
            }// End of no in Condition 2
                // Increment the number of events
            Number_of_Total_Events++;
        }// End of while loop
    }// End of static main method



    /**
     * Method to get the appropriate average of arriving customers per hour of service. The distributions were provided by the manager. 
     * They can be changed to any measured distribution.
     * 
     * @param Clock
     *            The current time
     * @return The average customers arriving for this hour
     */
    private static double getLambda(double clock) 
    {
        switch ((int) clock) 
        {
        case 0:
            return 1.0;
        case 1:
            return 2.0;
        case 2:
            return 3.0;
        case 3:
            return 4.0;
        case 4:
            return 5.0;
        case 5:
            return 6.0;
        case 6:
            return 7.0;
        case 7:
            return 8.0;
        default:
            return 0;
        }

    }


    /**
     * Find the first server that is free.
     * @param serverFree The arraylist in which to look for a free server
     * @return  The index of the position of the first free server
     */
    private static int getFreeServer(ArrayList<Server> serverFree) {
        for (Server server : serverFree) {
            boolean state = server.isState();
            if (state){
                return serverFree.indexOf(server);
            }
        }return -1;
    }// End of getFreeServer method

    /**
     * Find the first server that is busy.
     * @param serverFree The arraylist in which to look for a busy server
     * @return The index of the position of the first busy server
     */
    private static int getBusyServer(ArrayList<Server> serverFree) 
    {
        for (Server server : serverFree) 
        {
            boolean state = server.isState();
            if (state){
                return serverFree.indexOf(server);
            }
        }return -1;
    }// End of getFreeServer method

    /**
     * Count the free servers
     * @param serverFree The arraylist in which to look for a free server
     * @return The number of servers that are free
     */
    private static int freeServersNo(ArrayList<Server> serverFree)
    {
        int servers = 0;
        for (Server server : serverFree) {
            boolean state = server.isState();
            if (state) 
                servers++;
        }
        return servers;
    }// End of freeServersNo method

    /**
     * Count the busy servers
     * @param serverFree The arraylist in which to look for a busy server
     * @return The number of servers that are busy
     */
    private static int busyServersNo(ArrayList<Server> serverFree)
    {
        int servers =0;
        for (Server server : serverFree) {
            boolean state = server.isState();
            if (!state) 
                servers++;

        }
        return servers;
    }// End of busyServersNo method


    /**
     * Find the server with the lowest completion time
     * @param tnc_min The arraylist to search for completion times 
     * @return The index of the lowest time of completion
     */
    private static Server getNextTNC(ArrayList<Server> serverFree) 
    {
        double tnc_min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        Server index = null;
        for (Server server : serverFree) 
        {
            if(server.getTnc() < tnc_min) {
                tnc_min = server.getTnc();
                index=server;
            }

        }
        return index;
    }// End of getNextTNC method
}// End of Class
```

Comment: looks like homework to me..

Comment: No.. It's not a homework.. You see, there is no error in the code, I'm just trying to understand how it work and playing around with it.  I'm a beginner in Java programming so I feel that it would be faster to learn in an existing program code. I hope you understand and bear with such newbie questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just create an extra function and pass the number of servers as a parameter, like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        double lambdaA = 58.0;
        double lambdaS = 30.0;
        double tEnd = 8.0;
        /**
         * By starting and finishing shift with 1 server, almost 98.484848% of
         * customers wait more than 6 mins with the avg wait time at 218 hours.
         * With 2 servers the avg wait time is 13 hours with 69.1489% waiting
         * more than 6 mins. With 3 servers the avg waiting time is 26mins with
         * 0% of customers waiting more than 6 mins. Therefore the optimal
         * allocation will be by assigning 2 servers to start off the shift and
         * when the need arises, open a new position of service. If 1 server
         * alone starts, the fraction in close to 16%. By starting with 2
         * servers the fraction is 4.3%.
         */

    //  int nserv = 2;
        int[] servers = {5, 10, 15, 10};

        for (int nserv : servers) {
            simulateServers(lambdaA, lambdaS, tEnd, nserv);
        }

    }

    private static void simulateServers(double lambdaA, double lambdaS, double tEnd, int nserv) {


        // The starting seed for the random number generator
        long seed = 12342;

        //The number of times the simulation will be repeated for the average statistics
        int trials = 100;

        // Conduct a number of trials in order to get the average fraction of customers
        // waiting more than 6 mins. Use different seed in each trial.
        for (int i = 1; i <= trials; i++) {
            simulateNServers(lambdaA, lambdaS, tEnd, nserv, seed);
            seed++;
        }
        double trialAvg = fractionAvg / trials;
        percent = new DecimalFormat("0.#%");
        System.out.println("=============================================================================");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Average percent of customers waiting more than 6 minutes (100 trials) : 

" + percent.format(trialAvg));
        }
```

You can obtain the waiting time with the expression: "60 * ttwait / ttServed", at the end of the simulation:

```
// Get the index of the next available server
int id = getFreeServer(serverFree);
// BRANCH_1// Check if the condition to stop the simulation has been met.
if (q.isEmpty() && clock >= endTime
    && tnc == Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
percent = new DecimalFormat("0.0#%");
System.out.println("Average waiting time: " + 60 * ttwait
    / ttServed + " minutes");
```

.

```
Average waiting time: 1.9738361405998677 minutes
Server free fraction: 47.27%
Maximum queue length: 11
Total customers arrived: 468
Total customers served : 452
Total customers >6min  : 13
 fraction              : 0.028761061946902654
 server avg            : 2.1880341880341883
=============================================================================

Average percent of customers waiting more than 6 minutes (100 trials) : 3.2%
```

Comment: Thank you so much Danilo M.Oliveira ! :)

Comment: Is it the same method to do if I want to control the total customers arrival?

Comment: I have different answers from yours. . @danilo M.Oliveira
Average waiting time: 0.0 minutes
Server free fraction: 808.43%
Maximum queue length: 0
Total customers arrived: 470
Total customers served : 470
Total customers >6min  : 0
 fraction              : 0.0
 server avg            : 2.4191489361702128

Comment: your first question: yep, you can do the same.

Comment: your second comment:

I downloaded the code from https://github.com/cmdel/Queue-Simulation/blob/master/src/Simulate3.java and run as it is, to produce this output.

Comment: Q1 - Is it the same method to do if I want to control the total customers arrival::  I encounter error. What did I do wrong? @danilo M. oliveira  int[] ttServed = {50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300};

         for (double ta : ttServed) 
         {
          simulateServers(lambdaA, lambdaS, tEnd, nserv , ttserved);
          ++ttserved;
         }

Comment: You used the name of the array "ttserved" instead the name of the double variable of the for loop "ta".

I don't want to sound harsh, but you need to learn the basics of the language to use this simulator properly.

Comment: I'm a newbie in java programming and simulation. This is me trying to learn the logic and code as well. Please bear with me with such newbie questions. If you don't mind, can you show me how to do it?